# Find and and remove duplicate items in two files

Tags: shell

I have a file of 30,000 barcodes File1 eg

```
A6KAIIYY
A6KFNRGY
X6LPXV55
X6LQ5217
```

I need to read file1 then search for each barcode in another file of 35,000 barcodes (file2)
and delete the line if it finds it.
Is there a way I can shell script this?

Comment: If you are comfortable with databases, you can import to mysql or Sqlite.

Delete duplicates in access - https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Delete-duplicate-records-with-a-query-4e6c3183-689c-439d-9062-326c85d80a83

Mysql, DELETE (DUPLICATED <col>) FROM table WHERE <condition>

Sqlite, SELECT DISTINCT  <col> FROM  <table>;

Answer (score 4):

**`grep`** + **`mv`** solution:

```
grep -vf file1 file2 > /tmp/f2_tmp && mv /tmp/f2_tmp file2
```

- `-v` - select non-matching lines
- `-f FILE` - obtain patterns from `FILE`
- `/tmp/f2_tmp` - temporary file

Answer (score 0):

If all the the barcodes in file1 are in file2, concatenate the two files, sort, and use `uniq -u` to print only unique lines (those in file2 that weren't in file1):

```
cat file file2 | sort | uniq -u
```

Otherwise, sort each file, and use `diff file1 file2`, barcode only in file1 will be prefixed with '<' and those only in file2 with '>':

```
diff file1 file2 | grep -e '^> ' | sed 's/^> //'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The file the file 2 looks like                     A6EG0CBE    09702004 GUARANTEE2   3 30/04/2017 N
A6EG0CBM    09702004 AGREEMENT2   1 30/04/2017 N
A6EG0CCI    07852078 AGREEMENT2   1 30/04/2017 N
A6EG0CCQ    07852078 GUARANTEE2   3 30/04/2017 N
A6EG0CD2    07852078 PARENT_ACC 163 30/04/2017 N
A6EG0CD6    06836679 AGREEMENT2   1 29/04/2017 N   so the difference is more than just the barcodes. I need to search for the barcode string in file2 and if it matches delete the whole line